# Rails OAuth Profile Picture Definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I have successfully implemented an authentication system using the OAuth gems for Facebook and Twitter in my Rails 4 Application.

One of the main reasons I wanted to use social media authentication was to grab their profile pictures without having to have the user upload anything. I have successfully implemented this feature as well by grabbing the image out of the info hash returned by OAuth, except that the image returned is a very low quality copy. For instance, my profile picture on my twitter account is 400x400 pixels approximately, but the one returned by the OAuth hash is a 20x20 pixel image, and looks awful even as a small icon. Does anyone know of a configuration option or something that would allow me to receive the original picture and not a minimized one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install  and use ImageMagick and the RMagick gem to process and interpret images and photos. You will be able to scale, resize and transform pictures among others.

Good tuto:

http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/image-manipulation/

OR

> Not recommended:

In an App I have done (for learning) I had images saved in my db directly so that I could aply any css class to display them the way I wanted.

My controller was like this:

```
  def _show_image
    send_data(Base64.decode64(@food.image.data), :type => @food.image.mime_type, :filename => @food.image.filename, :disposition => 'inline')
  end
```

And I could get the image for the view like this (bootstrap class):

```
    <%=image_tag(url_for(:controller => 'foods', :action => '_show_image'), class: "pad-bot1 img-circle") %>
```

Comment: So I agree that that would work if I had a larger image file and I wanted to reduce it. To try and clarify, the problem that I am having is that the file itself that is returned is too small. For instance, when using the facebook graph API, you can give a query string ?type=large and it returns a full-size image, whereas the default without the query string is the 20x20 pixel image that I currently have. I need to know how to get this "type: large" image through the OAuth gem.